# What is the meaning of "Each of us Ends a remarkable person"?

Tags: meaning

In opening scene of Comedy movie Dinner for Schmucks (2010), Company CEO Lance Fender wants Tim to bring a person to dinner
at Fender's, so Tim will get Jacobson's postion,
which is empty. Compnay employee williams telling how
Tim should play this dinner game.

> Williams: **Each of us Ends a remarkable person** and invites them to
>   dinner at Fender's. We call it the "Dinner for Winners." Here's the
>   guy that I invited last year. There you go. Look at that. The guy
>   designed that suit. Real-life Iron Man. He took first prize.
>
> Tim: He's an idiot. (poiting to guy who wears iron suit)
>
> Williams: You got it.
>
> Tim: You invite idiots to dinner and make fun of them?

Comment: "Ends" makes no sense. Are you sure that is what is being said? Also, why is it capitalized?

Comment: You probably misheard.  It should be "finds" not "ends".

Comment: **No**, there is no misheard.

Answer (score 1):

This is a mistake in transcription. it should be "Each of us finds ...".

See [here](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=128712855).